# I dont know how to add Proxy to my Phantomjs script

Tags: python, proxy, phantomjs, casperjs

I've been having issues accessing websites and just realized that since the websites are controlled by my company I need to add a step in my script that shows the webpage I have my companies proxy IP or Im on their server. I hope that makes sense. For example if I access my companies webpage on my personal computer it says "Safari cant find server", but if I am logged into my company laptop I have no problems.

I know that I need to inject my proxy in phantomjs. Angel P suggested I use

```
--proxy=address:port specifies the proxy server to use (e.g. --proxy=192.168.1.42:8080).
--proxy-type=[http|socks5|none] specifies the type of the proxy server (default is http).
--proxy-auth specifies the authentication information for the proxy, e.g. `--proxy-auth=username:password).
```

I just don't understand how to add that into my script.

**Script below**

```
import os
import subprocess

#PJS_PATH = './phantom/bin/phantomjs'

#service_args = [
#'--proxy=idname:port#',
#'--proxy-type=http'
#]

#proxies = {'https': 'http://idname:port#'}
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

CASPER = "C:/casperjs/bin/casperjs"


SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'FCM.js')

params = CASPER +' '+ SCRIPT


print(subprocess.check_output(params,shell=True))
```

Where does the proxy go? I've gone to [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html), but don't understand how to compose it.

[here](http://www.codedisqus.com/CzVjqWjjje/casperjs-form-fill-returns-a-401.html) is what you will need to add to casperjs to help it work. Along with  Artjom B advice hope this helps someone.

Comment: Well, you didn't add those. It seems the previous question was not resolved, because you haven't accepted that answer. Why don't you first try to do this in the oommandline and see if the proxy settings actually help. I guess the page would look differently depending on whether the proxy is used or not.

Comment: Please forgive me for being totally noobish to this. This is super advanced for me at-least and I appreciate greatly every response I get. I will test this out now in the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily join the `service_args` to get a string:

```
saStr = " ".join(service_args)
```

and put that before the script:

```
params = CASPER +' '+ saStr + ' ' + SCRIPT
```

Comment: I wish I could just eat your brain like cereal. OMG why cant i just understand it like y'all. Thank you so much this was great!

Comment: Please don't. I need it for ... eating cereal.

Comment: in the above example the proxy address is 192.168.1.42:8080, but my company uses letters like bunnygum: port is a four digit number. does that matter?

Comment: A hostname should work, but you also try with an IP address. You find the IP by using "ping hostname" in the command prompt.

Comment: I fixed the issue. I needed to add something in my casperjs. I am so happy right now Thank you!!!